# XBee and Zigbee Door Lock Software Design Issue

Tags: home-automation, xbee

I am working on automating my home that is currently under construction. I am using a Raspberry Pi Model B + XBee Pro2 (http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B007R9U1QA?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o08_s00) as the hub.

I wanted to buy a Zigbee certified door lock and zeroed in on this one: http://www.zigbee.org/zigbee-products-2/#zigbeecertifiedproducts/productdetails3/5553fef3f7f0b6063927b3b4/

Based on its compliance document it supports all the functions and commands to open and close, etc.: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.knackhq.com/assets/54e658034b4f44e42fb18201/55560fb6a120797a6cb7b673/original/63551219008450202726355074577008941812zigbeehomeautomation1.2productinformationconformitystatementpicssdscopy.xml

```
<command receivedBy="server" code="0x00" name="LockDoor" mandatory="true">TRUE</command>
<command receivedBy="server" code="0x01" name="UnlockDoor" mandatory="true">TRUE</command>
<command receivedBy="client" code="0x00" name="LockDoorResponse" mandatory="true">TRUE</command>
<command receivedBy="client" code="0x01" name="UnlockDoorResponse" mandatory="true">TRUE</command>
```

So I think from a hardware point of view I should be sorted.

The issue is with software, I've been searching a lot (for 6 hours) and I've been unable to identify how I can get started with pairing the devices? Also I want to be able to keep my code generic so that I don't need to hardcode any of the codes, etc. So is there any existing framework where I can drop in the xml file and it recognizes the codes to send for the various door related operations?

I am proficient with C and NodeJS and in my mind I am planning to run a NodeJS server on the HUB that interacts with a service/daemon that I write in C that can talk with all Zigbee based Home Automation devices that I plan to install over time. I would hate to re-write the driver, since Zigbee does offer the universal plug and play promise.

If someone can give me some pointers to get started: example code, example architecture, etc. I will be much obliged.

Comment: have a look at this (https://deepsec.net/speaker.html#PSLOT223) - I wouldn't use a zigbee lock for anything atm